# Building a URL in HTML with Text Box Values

Tags: c#, html

I am adding a button to my website that will take the user to a website and fill in various variables from text boxes on my site.

Here is the markup code from my HTML Page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text="First Name:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTxtBox" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Last Name:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" Text="E-mail Address:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="EMailTextBox" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text="Description:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="DescTextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
    <button class="button" style="height:20px;width:120px" onclick="<%# String.Format("location.href='https://biznetsoftware.fastsupport.com/?first_name={0}&last_name={1}&email={2}&question=   {3}",FirstNameTxtBox.Text,LastNameTextBox.Text,EMailTextBox.Text,DescTextBox.   Text) %>" id="JoinChatButton">Join Chat</button>


</form>
</body>
```

The page doesn't go to the destination URL. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this  code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">
    void JoinChat(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = String.Format("https://biznetsoftware.fastsupport.com/?first_name={0}&last_name={1}&email={2}&question={3}", 
                    FirstNameTxtBox.Text,
                    LastNameTextBox.Text,
                    EMailTextBox.Text,
                    DescTextBox.Text); 
         Response.Redirect(url);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text="First Name:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="FirstNameTxtBox" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text="Last Name:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="LastNameTextBox" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" Text="E-mail Address:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="EMailTextBox" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text="Description:" Width="100px"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="DescTextBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

</div>
    <asp:Button class="button" style="height:20px;width:120px" id="JoinChatButton" Text="Join Chat" runat="server"OnClick="JoinChat" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is happening, is when I click the button, it doesn't go anywhere. It stays on the same page.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! That worked. At first, I got a "The Server Tag is not well formed" error when I cut the code and pasted it into my aspx page, but I simply did a Ctrl k,d and the code reformatted and now works perfectly! Thank you, again!

Answer (score 0):

First you forgot the ' character at the end of `location.href='...'`

Also, the page isn't going anywhere because location.href is not part of the onclick because you need to escape all of the double quote characters (") inside of the onclick

This should work:

```
<button class="button" style="height:20px;width:120px" onclick="<%# String.Format(\"location.href='https://biznetsoftware.fastsupport.com/?first_name={0}&last_name={1}&email={2}&question={3}'\", FirstNameTxtBox.Text,LastNameTextBox.Text,EMailTextBox.Text,DescTextBox.Text) %>" id="JoinChatButton">Join Chat</button>
```